# what is the formula for majority voting in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xls

I have an Excel sheet including `2000` tweets. Five annotators labeled each tweet as `Hate`, `Neutral`, and `Counterhate`. I want to create a new column indicating the majority voting on these labels for each tweet.

For example, if for a tweet, three annotators voted on `hate`, one voted `Counterhate`, and one `Neutral`, then the majority voting of this tweet should be `Hate`.

- *Question1*: Please let me know what the formula is to do this.
- *Question2*: what is the majority of voting for a tweet that the number of two classes are same? For example, two annotators voted as `Hate`, two as `Counterhate`, and one `Neutral`?

Following is the screenshot of my excel sheet and the formula I wrote, but it returns false.

| dex | Text | Label1 | Label2 | Label3 | #of Hate | #of Neutral | #of Counterhate | majority | Agreement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tweet1 | Hate | Hate | Hate | 3 | 0 | 0 | FALSE | 0.6 |
| 2 | tweet2 | Hate | Hate | Hate | 3 | 0 | 0 | FALSE | 0.6 |
| 3 | tweet3 | Neutral | Neutral | Neutral | 0 | 3 | 0 | FALSE | 1 |
| 4 | tweet4 | Hate | Hate | Hate | 3 | 0 | 0 | FALSE | 0.6 |
| 5 | tweet5 | Hate | Hate | Hate | 3 | 0 | 0 | FALSE | 0.4 |
| 6 | tweet6 | Hate | Hate | Hate | 3 | 0 | 0 | FALSE | 0.4 |
| 7 | tweet7 | Hate | Hate | Hate | 3 | 0 | 0 | FALSE | 1 |
| 8 | tweet8 | Neutral | Hate | Neutral | 1 | 2 | 0 | FALSE | 0.6 |
| 9 | tweet9 | Hate | Hate | Hate | 3 | 0 | 0 | FALSE | 0.6 |
| 10 | tweet10 | Counterhate | Neutral | Counterhate | 0 | 1 | 2 | FALSE | 0.4 |

I rewrite my formula:

```
=OR(IF(MAX(F2:H2)=F2,"Hate"),IF(MAX(F2:H2)=G2,"Neutral"),
  IF(MAX(F2:H2)=H2,"Counterhate"))
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) and edit your question to post your data and formula attempt as text.

Comment: That is  not how OR() works.  OR() doesn’t mean “choose one of these answers” it means perform the boolean OR function.  The values in an OR() must only be TRUE or FALSE.  `OR(“Hate”, “”, “”)` is not a valid or, and in fact your OR/IF formula resolves to `OR(“Hate”)` which will *always* be false, as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following for *Question 1* in `K2` cell:

```
=LET(values, {"Hate","Neutral","Counterhate"}, 
  counts, COUNTIF($C2:$E2,values), 
  INDEX(values, XMATCH(MAX(counts),counts)))
```

**Notes**:

1. *Question 2* is not excel related, it is business specific rule you need to define and then to apply that rule in Excel.
2. There is no need to use the helper additional columns you have for that. I obtain the result just based on **Label** columns:

[image: sample excel file]

`LET` is used for easier maintain the formula, creating variables representing portion of the formula will be repeated more than once.

```
counts, COUNTIF($C2:$E2,values)
```

Counts how many times the input range `$C2:$E2` contains the `values`.

```
INDEX(values, XMATCH(MAX(counts),counts))
```

Calculates the index position in `values` from the maximum number of repetitions.

The rest is just to expand down the formula in `K2` cell.

**Tip**: If the business rule for *Question2* is to consider for example `Neutral`, if two or more values have the same count. Then the previous formula can be modified as follow:

```
=LET(values, {"Hate","Neutral","Counterhate"},counts, 
  COUNTIF($C2:$E2,values), maxNum, SUM(-- 
  ISNUMBER(XMATCH(counts,MAX(counts)))), 
  IF(maxNum > 1,"Neutral",INDEX(values, XMATCH(MAX(counts),counts))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your responce. I exactly copied your Let() formula and pasted it in the k2, but I got the error "#NAME?"  how can I fix it?

Comment: @Amir did you check your version and the availability of the [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:~:text=The%20LET%20function%20assigns%20names,through%20Excel's%20native%20formula%20syntax) function. Just in case you have an older version

Comment: I checked my version, and I updated it now, but when I search LET in "Autosum", I don't find it. its version is 1808, Microsoft office professional 2019.

Comment: @Amir then you need to replace the names (`counts`, `values`) in every part of the formula and remove the `LET`, it will be longer, but it works. It seems `LET` is available for Excel 2021 and Microsoft O365 only, not for your version

Comment: do you mean this:  =counts, {"Hate","Neutral","Counterhate"},values, COUNTIF($C2:$E2,counts), INDEX(counts, XMATCH(MAX(values),counts))

Comment: I solved the problem of the old version by using the cloud Microsoft or Google excel sheet as the latest version. Now LET() function works. I see you added a tip. My research is "Hate detection", so hate is important. What happens if there are two hate, two counterhate, and one neutral? Can you modify your LET() function for that and explain how it works? thank you

Comment: @Amir, so Hate trumps over the rest if the maximum number of counts are the same, but what about: 2-Neutral, 2-Counterhate, 1-Hate?. I would suggest to add this information in your question so the information will be auto-consistent in the question. All cases should be considered

Comment: So definitely that tweet is not hateful, because we have one vote for hate and four votes for no-hate. the problem is what happens if the maximum number of votes for hate is same as the maximum number of votes for another label. thank you for your discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248773/discussion-between-david-leal-and-amir).